# How to create a secured node websocket client (unable to verify the first certificate problem)

Tags: javascript, node.js

## What is working

I created a node https/websocket server using [WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node).  Here a snippet on how I add key/cert :

```
import WebSockerServer from "websocket";
import fs from "fs";

const httpsSignalServer = https.createServer(
  {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./server.private.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./server.crt"),
  },
  (req, res) => {
    console.log("signal server : we have received a request");
  }
);
const signalWebsocket = new WebSockerServer.server({
  httpServer: httpsSignalServer,
});

signalWebsocket.on("request", (request) => onRequest(request));

httpsSignalServer.listen(8080, () => console.log("My signal server is listening"));
```

I have a React html web page that sends data to server above with WebSocket web api via wss :

```
new WebSocket("wss://192.168.230.138:8081");
```

My react app runs in an https server.  So far everything works.

## What is not working

The problem is my little node websocket client.  I am still using [WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node).  The [client documentation](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/docs/WebSocketClient.md) shows a tlsOptions to be given to the constructor.

Client code snippet:

```
var WebSocketClient = require("websocket").client;
var fs = require("fs");

const tlsOptions = {
  key: "./server.private.key",
  cert: "./server.crt",
};

var client = new WebSocketClient({
  key: fs.readFileSync(tlsOptions.key),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(tlsOptions.cert),
});
.
. 
.
client.connect("wss://localhost:8080/", "");
```

The client returns the message :

> Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Is there anyone out there who knows how to do the client setup with the tlsOptions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a perfectly functional simple chat script which is using secured connection. I added a couple of simple chat commands to enable or disable the chat from entering commands in chat.You could use this if you like or parts of it or even just see how I did it. Hope you find some use for it.

```
var maxLength = 100; // chars per chat
const port = 1441;
var JoinLeaveMsg = 1
var fs = require('fs');
const HTTPS = require('https');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const server = new HTTPS.createServer({
  cert: fs.readFileSync('C:/Certbot/live/MyDomain.com/cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('C:/Certbot/live/MyDomain.com/privkey.pem')
});
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server })

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
const now = new Date();
const tDate = now.toDateString();
const date = new Date(now);
const currentDate = date.toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(tDate + ' - ' + currentDate + " - New User Connected");

        ws.send(JSON.stringify(
            {
                name: "welcome",
                message: "wanna chat?"
            }
        ));

ws.on('message', function(message){
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    const createDOMPurify = require('dompurify');
    const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
    const window = new JSDOM('').window;
    const DOMPurify = createDOMPurify(window);
// START CONNECT
    if(message.type == "name"){
// START CHECKS FOR DOUBLE LOGIN

        var dirty = message.data;
        const ConnectingUser = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty);
        if (ConnectingUser != ''){
            wss.clients.forEach(function e(client) {
                var ConnectedUser = client.personName;
                if(ConnectedUser == ConnectingUser) {
                    client.send(JSON.stringify(
                        {
                            name: "***Server***",
                            message: "***We do not allow double logins!"
                        }
                    ));
                    client.send(JSON.stringify(
                        {
                            name: "***Server***",
                            message: " Disconnected..."
                        }
                    ));
                    client.close();
                }
            });
        }
// END CHECKS FOR DOUBLE LOGIN
        ws.personName = ConnectingUser;
        memberJoinedChatMsg(ws, ConnectingUser);
        return;
    }

// START INPUT DATA
    if(message.type == "message"){
        var ConnectedUser = ws.personName;
        if (ConnectedUser != ''){
            var dirty = message.message;
            const Message = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty);
            var string = Message;
            var temp = string.split(" ");
            var CommandOne = temp[0];
            var CommandTwo = temp[1];
            var CommandThree = temp.slice(2).join(" ");
            // lets process the messages and send to users
            if((Message) != "") {
// START COMMANDS
                // Do join/leave msg disable--------------------------------------------------------------------            
                if((CommandOne) == "/jpenable" || (CommandOne) == "!jpenable"){
                    JoinLeaveMsg = "1";
                    Msg ='***Join/Part message has been Enabled!';
                    sendMsgToAll(Msg)
                    MessageString ="";
                }
                // Do join/leave msg enable--------------------------------------------------------------------
                if((CommandOne) == "/jpdisable" || (CommandOne) == "!jpdisable"){
                    JoinLeaveMsg = "0";
                    Msg ='***Join/Part message has been Disabled!';
                    sendMsgToAll(Msg)
                    MessageString ="";
                }

// END COMMANDS
                if ((Message).length < maxLength) {
                    wss.clients.forEach(function e(client) {
                        
                        client.send(JSON.stringify(
                            {
                                name: ConnectedUser,
                                message: Message
                            }
                        ));
                        console.log("Sent: "+ConnectedUser+" "+Message);
                    });
                }else{
                    wss.clients.forEach(function e(client) {
                        if(client === ws)
                        client.send(JSON.stringify(
                            {
                                name: '***Server***',
                                message: "*** Your message exceeds "+maxLength+" characters!"
                            }
                        ));
                    });         
                };
                
            }else{
                // dont process if empty line entered
            };
        }
    }

// END INPUT DATA
})
    ws.on('close', function(message) {
            if(ws.personName){
            memberLeftChatMsg(ws);
            }
            ws.close();
        //console.log("Client Disconnected");
    });
    // END CONNECT
})

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}!`)
})

// FUNCTIONS
// complete Send Message To All
function sendMsgToAll(Msg){
    wss.clients.forEach(function e(client) {
        client.send(JSON.stringify(
            {
                name: "Server",
                message: Msg
            }
        ));
    }); 
};
// complete
function memberJoinedChatMsg(ws, ConnectingUser) {
    if(JoinLeaveMsg != "0"){
        wss.clients.forEach(function e(client) {
            client.send(JSON.stringify(
                {
                    name: "***Server***",
                    message: " &lt;<b>"+ConnectingUser+"</b>&gt; has entered chat!"
                }
            ));
        });
    }
};
// complete
function memberLeftChatMsg(ws) {
    if(JoinLeaveMsg != "0"){
        wss.clients.forEach(function e(client) {
            client.send(JSON.stringify(
                {
                    name: "***Server***",
                    message: " &lt;<b>"+ws.personName+"</b>&gt; has left chat!"
                }
            ));
        }); 
    }
};
```

I also have Dompurify installed using npm to help prevent entities being posted. Remember to open the port in your firewall or change the port number in the script. If you need the client side script including the html, .css let me know, I can upload those too :)

CLIENT SCRIPT:

```
(function() {
const sendBtn = document.querySelector('#send');
const messages = document.querySelector('#messages');
const messageBox = document.querySelector('#messageBox');
var ws;
var text = "Server: Server Offline!";
var sName = name;
function updateChat(element) {
        var name = element[0];  
        var message = element[1];
const now = new Date();
const tDate = now.toDateString();
const date = new Date(now);
const currentDate = date.toLocaleTimeString();
        if(sName == name){
        $('.responsive-html5-chat' + ' div.messages').append( '<div class="message"><div class="myMessage"><p>' + message + "</p><date>" + name + " " + currentDate + "</date></div></div>" );  
        }else{
        $('.responsive-html5-chat' + ' div.messages').append( '<div class="message"><div class="fromThem"><p>' + message + "</p><date>" + currentDate + " " + name + "</date></div></div>" );
        }
        setTimeout(function () { $('.responsive-html5-chat' + ' > span').addClass("spinner"); }, 100);
        setTimeout(function () { $('.responsive-html5-chat' + ' > span').removeClass("spinner"); }, 2000);
        $(".messages").scrollTop(function() { return this.scrollHeight; });
}

function responsiveChat(element) {
    $(element).html('<form class="chat"><span></span><div class="messages"></div><input type="text" id="msg" placeholder="Your message" autocomplete="off"><input id="send" type="submit" value="Send"></form>');
}

responsiveChat('.responsive-html5-chat');

function init() {
      if (ws) {
        ws.onerror = ws.onopen = ws.onclose = null;
        ws.close();
      }

      ws = new WebSocket('wss://MyDomain.com:1441');

      ws.onopen = function() {
          if(name) {
              ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                type: "name",
                data: name  
              }));
          }else{
            const dat = ['', 'Please <a href="https://MyDomain/login.php">Login</a> to chat!'];
            updateChat(dat);
            ws = null;
            return ;
          }
      }
      // START RECIEVED FROM SERVER
      ws.onmessage = function(event){
        var json = JSON.parse(event.data);
        var Name = json.name;
        var Message = json.message;
        if(name) {
            if (Name === "***Server***"){
                const dat = ['***Server***', Message];
                updateChat(dat);
            }else if(Name === "welcome" && name != '') {
                Message = 'Hi ' + name + ' ' + Message;
                const dat = ['', Message];
                updateChat(dat);
            }else{
                const dat = [Name, Message];
                updateChat(dat);
            }
        }
    
      }
      // END RECIEVED FROM SERVER
      ws.onclose = function(event) {
        if (event.wasClean) {
          ws = null;
        } else {
          const dat = ['', 'Server Offline!'];
          updateChat(dat);
          ws = null;
        }
      };
}
// START SEND TO SERVER
send.onclick = function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(name) {
        if (!ws) {
            const dat = ['', 'You are not connected... :('];
            updateChat(dat);
            ws = null;
            return ;
        }
        var messages = document.getElementById("msg").value;
        document.getElementById("msg").value = ''; // empty msg box
                
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
            type: "message",
            data: name,
            message: messages
        }));
    }else{
        const dat = ['', 'Please <a href="https://MyDomain/login.php">Login</a> to chat!'];
        updateChat(dat);
        ws = null;
        return ;
    }
};
init();
})();
```

Comment: Hello!  Is your websocket client is a web api or it is the client from  WebSocket-Node?  If you don't mind, I would like to see your client as well :)  I don't need the html nor the css.

Comment: it is node.js, I have npm installed as well. I will upload the client script for you